# Create build types for product flavors

Tags: android, gradle

I'm looking for how can I create build types directory for flavors.
Right now I have 2 flavors called `dev` and `prod` and I want to create debug and release directories in `app/src` folder.
My `app/src` folder looks like this:

```
 main
 androidTest
 test
 release
 debug
```

About what I'm trying to achive:
I'm trying to add a sufix to my package in debug mode. So I achived that in build types block. in addition I have set `minSdkVersion 21` in one of my flavors so that android gradle builds faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create directory that are the combination between build types and flavors naming them with this convention: `buildtypeFlavor`

For what you want to achieve you have to insert in your `build.gradle` file both build types configurations and flavors configurations.

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        }
        release {

        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
        prod {

        }
    }
}
```

Now you can create dirs under `src` to have the combination of both, in this case: `devDebug, devRelease, prodDebug, prodRelease`

```
root
|___module
    |___src
        |__devDebug
        |__devRelease
        |__prodDebug
        |__prodRelease
```